# copy/paste only certain files types in a directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, copy-paste

Wondering if there is a script I could run in a .bat file that would allow me to copy only certain file types in a directory, and then paste them in another directory

Example of contents of directory: **F:\testbatch\test1**

```
test_01.tcs
test_02.tcs
test_03.tcs
garbagefile_01.txt
garbagefile_02.txt
nothing.rtf
test.tpl
```

Lets say I want to copy all **.tpl** & **.tcs** files in from **F:\testbatch\test1** and paste them to:

**F:\testbatch\test2**

It should be noted that the destination directory **F:\testbatch\test2** will already have some of the same files as the source folder, and I need these files to be overwritten.

So my question here is twofold:

1 - What command that I can put in a batch script will only copy certain types of files?

2 - How can I make sure when these files are copied & pasted that they will overwrite the existing files of the same name(s)?

EDIT I have tried:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\me\Desktop 3\123" *.bin "C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop 3\456" /y
xcopy "C:\Users\me\Desktop 3\123" *.tpl "C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop 3\456" /y
```

but nothing gets copied at all.

Running Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Have you tried the obvious command... `copy`? (i.e.: `Copy F:\testbatch\test1\*.tpl F:\testbatch\test2`).  Copy also has an option for forcing overwrites without asking (see `copy /?`)..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What command that I can put in a batch script will only copy certain types of files?

Any command that accepts [wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html).

For example [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) or [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

---

#### How can I make sure when these files are copied they will overwrite existing files?

Use the [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) `/y` (Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file) option.

---

#### I want to copy all `.tpl` and `.tcs` files from F:\testbatch\test1 to F:\testbatch\test2

Use the following commands

```
xcopy F:\testbatch\test1\*.tpl F:\testbatch\test2 /y
xcopy F:\testbatch\test1\*.tcs F:\testbatch\test2 /y
```

---

#### Why isn't this working?

> I have tried:
>
> ```
> xcopy "C:\Users\me\Desktop 3\123" *.bin "C:\Users\Fiver\Desktop 3\456" /y
> xcopy "C:\Users\me\Desktop 3\123" *.tpl "C:\Users\Fiver\Desktop 3\456" /y
> ```

Your quotes are in the wrong place and you are missing a backslash.

The correct commands are:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\me\Desktop 3\123\*.bin" "C:\Users\Fiver\Desktop 3\456" /y
xcopy "C:\Users\me\Desktop 3\123\*.tpl" "C:\Users\Fiver\Desktop 3\456" /y
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust file and folder Copy
- [Wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder

Answer (score 1):

There is no command that directly lets you pick multiple extensions types to copy files only with that extensions. The way I do it is create a batch file with multiple `xcopy` calls.

In your case, you want to create a batch file with the lines.

```
xcopy F:\testbatch\test1\*.tpl F:\testbatch\test2 /y
xcopy F:\testbatch\test1\*.tcs F:\testbatch\test2 /y
```

So the short answer is batch file is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for my purposes was to image the source directory to another temporary one, but in the copy prompt only process *.pdf files

On windows I used XCOPY -

```
XCOPY "C:\utils\*.pdf" "D:\Backup\utilspdfs" /s /i
```

I then processed that folder, then copy pasted back into original folder.

You can do similarly with bash on gnulinux

```
cp -r source_directory/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} target_directory 2>/dev/null || :
```

Answer (score -2):

You may want to look into [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx).  It has a multitude of different switches that can be used to get the results you want.

Comment: Rather than saying "Use this" - a good answer recommending a tool tells you how to use the tool.

Comment: OK, noted.  I had seen other comments that encourage questioners to do a modicum of work/research on their own before asking for help.  Note that I had answered before the edit to the original question.  Sometimes, a gentle push in the right direction is all that's needed.

Comment: There's a specific meta post on this  [on meta which reflects the community consensus](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). The "do research" bit is more for questions than answers.